# HTTP Post with Lua

Tags: rest, lua, nodemcu

I am new in Lua world. I would to send data from NodeMCU with RESTApi and I am getting error. can you tell me what I write wrong

```
function func_http_post()
print("sending data")
body= '{"mode":"sync","messageType":"f15a15604014bb5f0ec0","messages":[{"sensor":"sensor1","value":"11","timestamp":1413191656}]}'
http.post('URL',
    'Content-Type: application/json\r\n'
  ..'Authorization: Bearer 363f74ab6fdf5dda293d2f16e7a5ac\r\n',
  body,
  function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
       print(code, data)
    else
      print(code, data)
    end
  end)
end
```

This is the output :

```
sending data
HTTP request failed
-1 nil
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Explain what 'URL' is?

Comment: Hi URL is a link like https://www.XXXXXX.com/XXXXXX/xxxxxx

Comment: I'm afraid we won't be able to help you unless we know the _public_ URL you're posting to. Take the [example from the docs](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/http/#httppost) and post to httpbin.org for comparison. Furthermore, you may want to [turn on debugging in the firmware](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/build/#debugging) to see if you get more useful output. It's worth mentioning there's an open issue wrt HTTPS: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1707